# How many subsets of F contain no more than one element from G

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given: $F = \{Q, K, B, L, I, M\}$ and $G = \{Q, K,B,M\}$, I want to solve:

> How many subsets of $F$ contain no more than one element from $G$?

The reasoning I used was that

1. Choose from: Q, K, B, M - 4 ways.
2. Discard rest of choices - 1 way.
3. L - 2 ways
4. I - 2 ways

This gives $ 4 \cdot 1 \cdot 2^2  = 16$ subsets.

Also side question is it correct that the number of unique subsets in $F$ would be $ 2^6 $ subsets? Is $\{L, K\}$ the same as $\{K, L\}$?  I was told that sets are unordered thus a unique subset is the same a as subset.

Comment: What do you mean by "discard rest of choices"?

Comment: @EricWofsey Originally I didn't have that line there but I felt it was weird to not specify that you've only chosen one letter and now the rest cannot be included in the subset, but I'm not sure if that is the right wording.

Comment: You don't have to include that line explicitly; when you are counting all the possibilities, it is implicit that you are not allowing any possibilities besides the ones you've named.

Comment: Hope this doesn't sound like a rant but almost everybody these days uses the word "unique" incorrectly.  The number of **different** subsets of $C$ is $2^6$.  (And I think you mean $F$ not $C$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost right, but you're missing the possibility that your subset contains *no* elements of $G$.  So instead of $4$, your first factor should be $5$, since you can contain $Q$, $K$, $B$, or $M$, or you can contain none of them.  So the answer is $5\cdot 2^2=20$.

On your side question, that's right, $\{L,K\}$ is the same as $\{K,L\}$.  There are $2^6$ total subsets of $F$ since for each of its $6$ elements you have $2$ choices (either contain that element or don't).